# SQL Query, if not exists add "NA"

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a way to check whether or not a parameter exists from a SQL query, if it doesnt exists I'd like to declare the parameter as a string with 'na' value in the output/response.
Not sure if this is supported in a SQL query or not? I can't find anything similar to my below "brainstorm" when researching it.

Any SQL guru out there able to give some input into this matter?

```
SELECT parameter1, parameter2 FROM 'test' IF parameter2 NOT EXISTS parameter2 = 'na'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT parameter1, COALESCE(parameter2, 'NA') as parameter2
FROM test;
```

This assumes that "not exists" means the value is `NULL`.  Otherwise, you need a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this one as per required:**

SELECT parameter1, COALESCE(parameter2, 'NA') AS parameter2
FROM test

**Full Examples as per required:**

SELECT [Name], COALESCE([Tier], 'NONE') AS [Tier]
FROM [dbo].[Customer]

**Full examples as per required:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If any issue exist then please reply with comments